# Undefined method for array csv export

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error when trying to export to a csv:

```
undefined method `dd_export' for #<Array:0x00007fc4836f1798>
```

I think it's the relationship between the model and controller, but  can't work out why this is. I'm using a custom `dd_export` convention as more csv download may be added, and also using `to_csv` doesn't seem to export what's required in my model.

**day_degree_export.rb**

```
class DayDegreeExport < ApplicationRecord 
  def self.dd_export
    attributes = %w{Date Min_Temp Max_Temp}
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes
        all.each do |dd|
          csv << [
            dd['date'],
            dd['variables'][1]['value']
            dd['variables'][0]['value']
          ]
        end
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

**day_degree_export_controller.rb**

```
class DayDegreeExportController < ApplicationController

dd_results
 data = HTTParty.get("url_link")
 @ddexport = JSON.parse(data.body)

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @ddexport['data'].dd_export, filename: "ddexport.csv" }
 end
end

end
```

I have required csv in my application.rb.

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong: you're trying to call `dd_export` on the array that is returned by `@ddexport['data']` and the array doesn't have that method. Are you trying to use the method `dd_export` that you defined on the `DayDegreeExport` class?

Comment: Thats correct. Instead of call @ddexport['data'].to_csv the defining that in my model, I want to def the custom name dd_export.

Comment: if I call @ddexport['data'].to_csv and define it in my model as self.ddc_export it seems to ignore what's called in the method anyway.

Comment: BTW, are you missing a `def` in front of `dd_results` in your controller? Are you wanting to store `@ddexport['data']` to the database?

Comment: No not looking to store, just export.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `@ddexport['data'].dd_export`, you'd have to patch the Array class for `dd_export`, but a better way to implement it is to save your array as `DayDegreeExport` records.

```
class DayDegreeExportController < ApplicationController

  def dd_results
    data = HTTParty.get("url_link")
    @ddexport = JSON.parse(data.body)
    DayDegreeExport.create(@ddexport) # you can do this if your @ddexport is array of hashes with matching keys

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data DayDegreeExport.dd_export, filename: "ddexport.csv" }
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks @nayjaw. Thus doesn't work as I get the error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation day_degree_exports does not exist. The data is collected from an API and not stored on a database.

Comment: If you don't intend to save the records you can define a class without ActiveRecord. Your problem is that you're calling a "model" class method with a set of data from API which is actually array of hashes so it's not related to each other in any way. You can refer to the jvillian's answer for a much better implementation or simplify it to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not intending to store `@ddexport['data']`, then there is no need for `DayDegreeExport` to inherit from `ApplicationRecord`. Instead, I would suggest you do something like:

```
# app/services/day_degree_export_service.rb

class DayDegreeExportService

  CSV_ATTRIBUTES = %w(
    Date 
    Min_Temp
    Max_Temp
  ).freeze

  attr_accessor *%w(
    args
  ).freeze

  class << self 

    def call(args={})
      new(args).call
    end

  end

    def initialize(args)
      @args = args
    end

    def call
      CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
        csv << CSV_ATTRIBUTES
        dd_export_data.each do |dd|
          csv << [
            dd['date'],
            dd['variables'][1]['value']
            dd['variables'][0]['value']
          ]
        end
      end
    end

  private 

    def dd_export_data
      @dd_export_data ||= JSON.parse(HTTParty.get("url_link"))['data']
    end

end
```

Which you would use something like:

```
class DayDegreeExportController < ApplicationController

  def dd_results
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data DayDegreeExportService.call, filename: "ddexport.csv" }
    end
  end

end
```

Now, a few comments:

1) I *never* use CSV so I have *no* idea whether the code is going to work. I took a look at the docs and I think this may be close, but you may have to fiddle with it.

2) A PORO (plain old ruby object) gets the job done here. You can see I suggest you place it in a `services` directory and rails will pick it up automatically.

3) In the class-level `call` method, I include optional `args`. That's just for example purposes. Some other time you might want to pass in arguments.

4) For services, I like to use the `call` method instead of service-specific methods like `dd_results`. It's just a me thing. But, then, you don't have to think about what to call your methods in your service. As long as your services and their purpose have a 1:1 relationship, then the class name describes what the service does instead of the method name.

5) Using `class << self` creates class methods. It's basically the same as doing `def self.call`.

6) This all assumes, I supposed, that `JSON.parse(HTTParty.get("url_link"))['data']` returns an array of data and that each datum has the keys that you indicate.